# C++ templates: C2143 error in VS2017 but compiles in VS2013

Tags: c++

I have this code snippet which gets compiled in VS2013 but in VS2017 gives me C2059 error.

```
template <typename ArgumentType>
class MyFunction: public std::unary_function<ArgumentType, ArgumentType>
{
// rest of the code here
}
```

> error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "," vor "<"

I looked up the documentation of the error [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2143?view=vs-2019) but cannot figure out the reason for the error.

I tried

```
template <typename ArgumentType>
class MyFunction: public std::unary_function<typename ArgumentType, typename ArgumentType>
{
}
```

And still get the same error.

Comment: You are getting this error because `unary_function` was removed since c++17.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::unary_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function) is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17. If you use the latest VS2017 and didn't choose a different standard than C++17, it is expected that your code fails to compile because there is no `std::unary_function`.

There is generally no need for `std::unary_function` and friends anymore. All it does is add two typedefs to your class, which you could do by hand if you really wanted to. But it's also expected that code accepting arbitrary functors would not rely on the presence of some member typedefs, which is why there should be no need for any of this. If removing the `std::unary_function` base class breaks some other code, the right action is to fix that code.

Comment: Thank :) What is the replacement for std::unary_function then?

Comment: @abhilb What happens if you just remove the `std::unary_function` base class? Is there any code that actually relies on what it does?

Comment: @abhilb lambdas ;-)

Comment: removing the `std::unary_function` worked. Thanks :)